# Seeking counsel about [console]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag [console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console) (8033 questions) isn't absolutely horrible, but it covers a large range of things, such as the [Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application), the [JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-do-i-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console), the [Unix console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-sh-script-in-an-unix-console-mac-terminal), and the [Rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails). It has to be used in combination with another tag rather than by itself.

Should it be split up into specific tags about each different console?

Comment: No. Unless you want a bazillion tags like `[firebug-console]`, `[ie-console-sucks]`, etc.

Comment: Are these questions so common that they all need their own tag? BTW, that unix one, isn't unix, but osx, and off topic...

Comment: @Braiam "How to run a .sh-script in an Unix console/Mac terminal?". Also, OSX is Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-mac-os-x-unix

Comment: So, are you saying that it isn't a userspace question, but a kernel one?